# Sending email in Asp.net / C# with attachments - Issues with Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

In an ASP/C# application I'm sending an email with 3 file attached. The 3 files are the same type, same extension and more or less same size ( but none are empty ). 
The email is sent correctly. If I open it using outlook, I have no problems. I can see the body, and the 3 files attached.

But here is my issue: If I send that mail to a Gmail Adress, then on Gmail I can see only 2 attachments.

[image]

And if I click on the *download all attachment* icon ( on the right ), it will download the 2 visible attachment + the third one but empty.

It's a really weird issue.

Also there is a 4th attachment which is an embedded image. And this image is display correctly in the mail body.

Here is the code I'm using to send the mail:

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("SMTP_IP_ADRESS", SMTP_IP_PORT);

            mail.From = new MailAddress("MYEMAIL@DOMAIN.COM");

            mail.To.Add("GMAIL_EMAIL");
            mail.To.Add("OUTLOOK_EMAIL");

            mail.Subject = "MSN "+Request.Params["nameMsn"];

            Attachment imageAttachment = new 
            Attachment(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/images/image.png")));
            string contentID = "logoCare";
            imageAttachment.ContentId = contentID;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = "<html><body>Have a good day.<br/>Best regards. <br/><br/><img width='200' 
            src=\"cid:"
                 + contentID + "\"></body></html>";

            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
                var attachment = new Attachment(file.InputStream, file.FileName, 
                MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
                mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }

            mail.Attachments.Add(imageAttachment);

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

The third attachment you see empty can possibly be the CID embedded image that web based email clients (like Gmail) can't manage, meanwhile it works with desktop email clients like Outlook. Can you verify this?
Please take a look at [here](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help. But I forgot to mentionned that there is a 4th attachment which is an image embedded in the mail. So in the "for loop", I have 3 files that's gonna be added. And only 2 showing.